# Compare date range in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I am having a daterange in pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndexDatetimeIndex as :

```
(['2021-03-21', '2021-03-22', '2021-03-23', '2021-03-24',
               '2021-03-25', '2021-03-26', '2021-03-27', '2021-03-28',
               '2021-03-29', '2021-03-30', '2021-03-31', '2021-04-01',
               '2021-04-02', '2021-04-03', '2021-04-04'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

Moreover series data as:

```
2021-03-27    2
2021-03-28    1
2021-03-30    1
2021-03-31    2
2021-04-04    3
```

Now if I want to get a dataframe with all dates and its opposite value as it is and if any date is missing it should give answer as that date as 0 value.
Output format should be:

```
2021-03-22    0
2021-03-23    0
2021-03-24    0
2021-03-25    0
2021-03-26    0
2021-03-27    2
2021-03-28    1
...
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html), only necessary `DatetimeIndex` in `Series` for matching `idx`:

```
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2021-03-21', '2021-03-22', '2021-03-23', '2021-03-24',
                       '2021-03-25', '2021-03-26', '2021-03-27', '2021-03-28',
                       '2021-03-29', '2021-03-30', '2021-03-31', '2021-04-01',
                       '2021-04-02', '2021-04-03', '2021-04-04'])


print (s)
2021-03-27    2
2021-03-28    1
2021-03-30    1
2021-03-31    2
2021-04-04    3
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

---

```
s.index = pd.to_datetime(s.index)
s = s.reindex(idx, fill_value=0)
print (s)
2021-03-21    0
2021-03-22    0
2021-03-23    0
2021-03-24    0
2021-03-25    0
2021-03-26    0
2021-03-27    2
2021-03-28    1
2021-03-29    0
2021-03-30    1
2021-03-31    2
2021-04-01    0
2021-04-02    0
2021-04-03    0
2021-04-04    3
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

If want reindex by [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) instead `idx` use it:

```
s = s.reindex(pd.date_range('2021-03-21', '2021-04-04', freq='D'), fill_value=0)
```